# Setting object array keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an array of objects in JS, this is my structure:

```
$("li.user_task").each(function() {
    tasks.push({
        taskid: $(this).data("taskid"),
        productid: $(this).data("product-id"),
        productposition: $(this).data("product-position")
    });
});
```

This is working nicely, my output on console.log():

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
productid: 2
productposition: 1
taskid: 150
__proto__: Object
1: Object
productid: 1
productposition: 1
taskid: 151
__proto__: Object
2: Object
productid: 2
productposition: 2
taskid: 155
__proto__: Object
3: Object
productid: 1
productposition: 3
taskid: 157
__proto__: Object
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
```

I don't want my keys starting from 0 though, in this very example I'd actually like the field "taskid" to be the key for the object, how could I achieve this?

Comment: these are array indexes starting from zero, not your keys.

Comment: If you use custom Keys in an Array e.g. 2 the key 0 and 1 gets an undefined and the array has a length of 3 (thats not a got practice)

Comment: Looks like you are talking about index. Not key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
 $("li.user_task").each(function() {
  tasks[$(this).data("taskid")]=({
     taskid: $(this).data("taskid"),
     productid: $(this).data("product-id"),
     productposition: $(this).data("product-position")
 });
});
```

unless, your taskid is not unique.

and yes as @Bernhard mentioned... with integers as key of an array.. the length of an array differs....

Comment: Thats not good... try this:                                           var test = [];
test[150] = {};
console.log(test); Then you know whats the problem with that